# How to detect screen boundaries with Flame in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flame

I want to detect when an object goes outside of the screen in Flame Flutter. I think there is two way to accomplish this either with `Collidable` mixin or with Forge2D. If possible explain it in both of them.

Flame version: flame: 1.0.0-releasecandidate.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is way overkill to use `Forge2D` for this (that complicates a lot of other things too). But you can use the built-in collision detection system, or you can check in the update-loop whether it is within the screen or not (this would be the most efficient).

By using the collision detection system we can use the built-in `ScreenCollidable` and you can do something like this:

```dart
class ExampleGame extends FlameGame with HasCollidables {
  ...
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    add(ScreenCollidable());
  }
}

class YourComponent extends PositionComponent with HasHitboxes, Collidable {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    // Change this if you want the components to collide with each other
    // and not only the screen.
    collidableType = CollidableType.passive;
    addHitbox(HitboxRectangle());
  }

  // Do note that this doesn't work if the component starts
  // to go outside of the screen but then comes back.
  @override
  void onCollisionEnd(Collidable other) {
    if (other is ScreenCollidable) {
      removeFromParent();
    }
  }
}
```

and by just calculating it in the `update`-loop:

```dart
class YourComponent extends PositionComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    final topLeft = absoluteTopLeftPosition;
    final gameSize = gameRef.size;
    if(topLeft.x > gameSize.x || topLeft.y > gameSize.y) {
      removeFromParent();
      return;
    }
    final bottomRight = absolutePositionOfAnchor(Anchor.bottomRight);
    if(bottomRight.x < 0 || bottomRight.y < 0) {
      removeFromParent();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I also recommend that you update to Flame 1.0.0 now when it is released. :)

Answer (score 0):

**There is no longer a `Collidable` mixin**.

See the [Flame documentation](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.6.0/flame/collision_detection.html?highlight=rectanglehitbox#migration-from-the-collision-detection-system-in-v1-0)